# Multiple comboboxes not populating

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using visual studio 2012 and using vb.net to code a windows forms. One of the forms has two comboboxes. I populate them from a list that reads from a database. The code below is in the form load method

```
Dim studentList as New List(Of clsStudent)
studentList = dbClass.loadStudents()
For Each student In studentList
    Dim entry As String = "row of info for combobox"
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(entry)
Next

Dim catalogList as New List(Of clsCatalog)
catalogList = dbClass.loadCatalog()
For Each catalog In catalogList
    Dim entry As String = "row of info for combobox"
    Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(entry)
Next
```

The code for combobox1 works and populates correctly. The problem is that the second one does not. And when I switch the two codes' order, then combobox2 works while combobox1 does not. I feel like the .load methods are canceling the other or something. Thx in advance

EDIT: Alright I figured it out. It seems the database connection was closed by the time the .loadcatalog method was called. So I just reopened the connection for the .loadcatalog. It does not seem efficient but it worked. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Did you get error messages? Check if you have exception trapped and ignored somewhere.

Comment: Do you have any code in the ComboBox's SelectedChanged event?  Otherwise, we need to see more code to help you.

Comment: Step through your code and see what `entry` looks like. nothing looks obviously wrong.

Comment: there is no error code and the code does work. But only one combobox works and it seems to be whatever combo box code comes first is the one working.

Comment: set a breakpoint and be sure that there is data in `catalogList`.  BTW neither loop is needed, you could bind the lists to each combobox as the DataSource

Comment: Where is this code located?  The `Load` event handler maybe?  Almost certainly there is an exception being thrown but you're just not seeing it.  Watch the Output window as that code is executed and you should see it or you can wrap the code in a `Try...Catch` block.  Almost certainly you are doing something wrong in your `dbClass` class and the second call fails regardless of what that second call is.

Comment: When i stepped through my code, there is no data to catalogList but when I move the .loadcatalog() above the .loadStudent(), then there is data in catalogList while studentList is empty. the second .load method will not work for some reason